# Spring Data ElasticSearch Is it possible to get the "took" field from the response

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

When I query from elasticsearch, I get a response:

```
{
"took": 16,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
```

Is it possible to get the "took" value using spring data elasticsearch?

EDIT:

This is how we query to the elasticsearch:

```
SearchHits<SearchPo> findByAllAttributes(String searchText) {

return elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(buildHeaderSearchQuery(searchText),
    SearchPo.class, IndexCoordinates.of("search");
```

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to query ES?

Comment: Hi Val, thanks for replying. I included the code we use for querying to elasticsearch. Looking forward for your response

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retrieve that information using `ElasticsearchRestTemplate`. As you can see [from the code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/erhlc/ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java#L412-L420), the `took`information is [available inside `SearchResponse`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/search/SearchResponse.java#L192) but `SearchDocumentResponseBuilder.from(SearchResponse)` [doesn't make it available](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/erhlc/SearchDocumentResponseBuilder.java#L60-L71) and only returns SearchHits.

What you could do is sub-class `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` and overload (not override!) the `search` method in order to return the raw `SearchResponse` so you can then call `SearchResponse.getTook()` from your code.

Edit (by P.J.Meisch): Create an issue in [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues) to have this added to the `SearchHits<T>` and feel free to contribute a pull request for that.

Comment: thanks for your response. Looks like it's too complicated as we only just want to measure the time it takes for the elasticsearch to run the query... Do you know any way how to measure the time it takes to query the elasticsearch aside from getting the "took" field?

Comment: Whatever you get from took doesn't include any latency between your app and ES, so it doesn't really show a real picture from the user standpoint. If you need the latter, then you can simply time your call

Comment: We are measuring time on different levels: 
1. from front endpoint to our backend endpoint
2. from backend endpoint to elasticsearch
3. from elasticsearch to elasticsearch (time it takes for the query)

We are in number 3 and we want to measure it as well to know which part/level we need to improve

Comment: @Java2Avaj See the edit by P.J.Meisch, thanks P.J. 